# Proof explanation: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=0 $ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=0 $ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$

**Proof:**

Let $m:=\lfloor|z|\rfloor $, then for $n>m$:$$\left \lvert \frac{z^n}{n!}\right \rvert=\frac{|z|^m}{m!}\cdot \frac{|z|^{n-m}}{(m+1)\cdot \ldots \cdot n}\leq |z|^m\cdot \left \lvert \frac{z}{m+1}\right \rvert ^{n-m}$$

Since $ \left \lvert \frac{z}{m+1}\right \rvert<1$ and $|z|^m$ being a constant, we can conclude that as $n\to \infty$ we get $0$.

I don't understand why $m$ is defined like that... why does it matter in the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m$ is defined the way it is because that's the exact point where the increase in $n!$ becomes larger than the increase in $|z^n|$ as $n$ grows, so it's at that point the absolute value of the fraction starts shrinking. You could use a larger $m$, if you wanted. But for a smaller $m$, the fraction would still be increasing in size.

Comment: Why does it include the floor-function? Because factorials are only defined for positive integers?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic The floor function is, strictly speaking, unnecessary. The exact properties of $m$ doesn't really matter much, just as long as it's big enough. It is $n$ that must be an integer. However, since $n$ is an integer, and we're comparing $n$ to $m$, it makes aesthetic sense to make sure $m$ is an integer as well. I do think you're overthinking this, though. It doesn't really matter what $m$ is, but **some $m$ must be chosen**. The authors here chose the smallest possible $m$, because it made them happy.

Answer (score 1):

Using $m$ as the modulus of $z$ is not the only way to prove the limit, but it's likely one of, if not the, easiest ways. The reason they define it like this is to show that, no matter how large $\left|z\right|$ is, eventually $n!$ will become infinitely larger than $\left|z^n\right|$. This is through the manipulation into an inequality with $2$ factors, one which is a constant and the other going to $0$ in modulus as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Why does it include the floor-function? Because factorials are only defined for positive integers?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic It includes the floor function to ensure that the very next value of integer $n$ chosen is larger than the modulus of $z$, due to the factorials being used here implicitly only using non-negative integers (you could define non-integral factorials using the Gamma function, but that's not necessary here). It could have just as easily been anything larger, like the ceiling function, floor or ceiling result plus $1$, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Another way that highlights the same idea...

Pick a positive integer $m$ such that $m > |z|$. Then, for $n>m$,
\begin{multline*}
\ln(n!\,/\,\left|z\right|^{n})=\ln(n!)-n\ln\left|z\right|=\left(\ln n+\cdots+\ln m\right)+\left(\ln(m-1)+\cdots+\ln2\right)-n\ln\left|z\right|\\
\geq\left(n-m\right)\ln m-n\ln\left|z\right|=n\left(\ln m-\ln\left|z\right|\right)-m\ln m=nC_{1}-C_{2}
\end{multline*}
where $C_{1}>0$ and $C_{2}$ are constants depending on $|z|$.
Exponentiating, we see that $n!\,/\,|z|^{n}$ diverges.

**Moral of the story**. Sometimes it's easier to think about these things from the additive perspective.